# Initialize global pointer to (virtual) object with anonymous subclass instance in C++

Tags: c++

Consider the following virtual class:

```
class Base {
    Base(size_t param);

    virtual double func_a(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual double func_b(int z) = 0;
}
```

Essentially, you would instantiate this class with a parameter which is used by the collection of functions which are overridden by subclasses. I will pass references to objects of this type in order to parameterize other functions, at which time I create anonymous subclass implementations.

Catch: there are 3 (pairs of) implementations of `Base`'s functions which I use *all the time*. I would like to have 3 global variables in my header referring to instances of these implementations. So I have:

```
//Base.h
class Base { ... }

Base * impl_one;
Base * impl_two;
Base * impl_three;
```

I've tried numerous ways of getting an anonymous class declared inline and stored in these variables in `Base.cpp`, but they all cause errors of different kinds:

```
//gives "[anonymous class] cannot be defined in a type specifier"
impl_one = new class : public Base { ... }

//gives "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" error
class P : public Base { ... }
impl_one = new P(64);
```

and so on. But if possible I don't want to have to write a `prep()` method that I call at the top of `main` which sets the global values externally. Is there a way to create one-time anonymous subclasses of virtual classes and store them in variables at the same time as if I had done `Base * impl_one = new Base(64)` and had no virtual methods?

Thanks~

Comment: You *can* do `Base* impl_one = new P(64);` in your cpp file.

Comment: thanks for promptness! when I tried that, I got a `redefinition of impl_one` compile error. thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need a global pointer and not a global variable of that type (i.e. why work with `new` at all?)

Comment: I suppose I don't strictly need the pointer, and it may be a mistake to do so. my reasoning is that I need to pass `impl_one` as a parameter to many functions, and I habitually try to pass pointers to stuff in order to avoid large stack-copy calls.

Comment: I've continued reading around and have seen the suggestion in a related case to use a tuple of lambdas. This might be worth calling a "different question" but can you make lambdas declared in this way contain shared state?

Comment: @Quintana: I assume mksteve's edited answer solves your Problem? Aside from that, I think pass-by-reference is the more idiomatic approach in c++ to prevent stack-copy calls (for small pods, pass-by value is usually still the best thing to do), But I fully understand, If you don't want to large-scale refactor your existing code without clear benefits.

Comment: @MikeMB thanks for that point. I will have to read more about use of references, because it seems like it has some great advantages (i've already run into irritation situations due to not being able to take pointer of a temporary). but yes MKsteve did answer the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class definition needs a semi-colan after it to complete it.
Otherwise the next identifier is treated as an instance of the class.

A global variable can be declared (with no initialization.

```
extern Base * impl_one;
```

and then used in the .cpp file, but you need to 'confirm' the type.

```
//gives "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" error
class P : public Base { ... };  // <<<< added ';'
Base * impl_one = new P(64);
```

The above code compiled for me (filling out constructor and so-forth).

Comment: Thanks for catching semicolon, editor put it there but I forgot to type it here. I still see "c++ requires type specifier". To be sure, did you define impl_one as `Base *` in the header? It seems to me that the compiler thinks that line in the implementation is a declaration, not just assignment to existing variable? thanks again.